# Firebase Database Query in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to do a query in Firebase database: if data is entered in "Detection name" node then it query the same data in "Trained Person Names" node and if both are equal then it fetch all child nodes of same name only not all values.

if child in detection name node is maarij then search for maarij in trained person name and fetch all info of maarij only.

Database:

[image: if child in detection name node is maarij then search for maarij in trained person name and fetch all info of maarij only.]

i tried to do a query using this code but it gives all data saved in Trained Person Names node. i want only specific data and info of that name if "detection name" child is found in "Trained Person Names" node.

```
final Query mydata= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Trained Person Names");
    mydata.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            final Query myquery =   detection_Name.orderByChild("Detection name").limitToLast(1)
                    .equalTo(String.valueOf(trained_Name.orderByChild("Guest Name")));
            Log.i("33","VALUE OF DATASNAPSHOT:"+dataSnapshot.getValue());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Thanks!!

Comment: 1) How is your `detection_Name` variable initialized? 2) Your `myquery` is never executed, so can't in any way affect the `Log.i` output.

Comment: 1.initialized in above code for retrieving detection name data and it works fine.2.yes my query is not executed i don't know how to start this query i just made this don't know how to use.

Comment: You can execute the query and get is results with something like `myquery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {...`

Comment: thanks! i tried this as you said it gives null because no data change in Trained Person Name nodes. detection name is need to search in Trained Person name node if found then give all of its info but i don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my problem. i fetched the node detection name node in my code than send this name to trained person name node and get only info of specific person not all of them.

```
    trained_Name.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       String detected_name = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child(detect_Name.toLowerCase()).getValue());
       Log.i("data","Detected Person Info Only:"+" "+ detected_name);
       String formattedData=formatString( detected_name);
       tv1.setText(formattedData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

i retrieved the last name of detected person node by followinfg code:

```
    detection_Name.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            String last_name = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());
           detect_Name= last_name;
            Log.i("Retrieve name only:", String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue()));
            

        }

        @Override

        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you are doing the wrong brother Because the name is not a unique word, Use only unique param which will not repeat anywhere. Then you can do your task properly. Create a unique id and save that value in "Detection name" table. Use that value as a key in "Trained Person Names" table. Now, you have to do one thing first get that value from "Detection name" table and use Like this:

```
final Query mydata= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Trained Person Names");
mydata.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        final Query myquery =   detection_Name.orderByChild("Detection name").limitToLast(1)
                .equalTo(String.valueOf(trained_Name.orderByChild("Guest Name")));
        Log.i("33","VALUE OF DATASNAPSHOT:"+dataSnapshot.getValue());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

You can create a unique value like this:

```
String uniqueId = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().toString();
```

Comment: thanks @Sandeep Malik. i retrieved the names from detection name node and do a query using this name but it also not work for me.